# Returned object changes private reference variable values

Tags: java, oop

Say I have a class with a reference type variable in it. I don't want the stored values of the object that this variable stores to be able to change, but I want to be able to get the object itself/access its values. This calls for making it private and creating a getter, but no setter. Doing this however only limits my ability to change the object that the variable points to, but it doesn't prevent me from changing the values of the object itself.

```
private void program(){

    Test test = new Test(3);

    out.println(test.getA().a); // initial value, prints 3

    test.getA().a = 4; // changes referenced value through getter, even though the object is private, and has no setter

    out.println(test.getA().a); // changed value, prints 4

}

class Test{
    private A a;

    public Test(int a){
        this.a = new A(a);
    }

    public A getA(){
        return a;
    }
}

class A{
    public int a;

    public A(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

In the code above I can use the getter to access the object's values, even though I made the variable private to try to prevent this from happening. The only way that I see around this is to create a new A object that I return every time I call the getter method, but to me this seems inefficient as it takes up unnecessary space in memory.

Is there a better way of reading the object while still preventing change or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem and there are 2 main solutions:

1. The way you described with copy-constructor or clone() method in getter
2. You can make your A class immutable - just make all fields final and initialize it once through constructor or nested builder

Also i advise not to make value-type fields public AT ALL

Usefull links:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-object
- https://www.journaldev.com/129/how-to-create-immutable-class-in-java
- https://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa15/classes/09-immutability/

Comment: As for your second solution, the 'a' attribute is supposed to be able to be changed, I just don't want it to be changed outside of the Test class. And I set it to public just for this example, I realize that I shouldn't set value-type fields to public in actual code. As for your first solution, my earlier question still stands: wouldn't cloning the object just take up unnecessary space? or is this just the only way around the problem?

Comment: No, you can't make your mutable object editable by reference only from one particular class. And, of course, cloning uses some extra processor and memory resources. BUT if you want to modify A object in Test class, why you can't just make it immutable and build a new instance with changed fields when it's required? It will solve the performance issue. Getter is supposed to be executed more frequently than, f.e, setter.